# Read file contents in python conditionally

Tags: python, file-read

I am trying to read one chromosome sequence from a genome file in python. The format of the genome file is like the following but with more lines of sequence for each chromosome:

Chr1

ATCGTGTGATGGTGCGTAGATGCTGAT

GCTGATGTGTCGAGCGATGCTGAGTCG

Chr2

TGCGTGATGCTGAGCGATGCTGATGCT

TAGCTGACCACACACCTGTTTTGTAGG

Chr3

CAGTCGTAGCGATGCTGATGATGCTGA

GGTTGGTTGGCGGACCACCATTACTAT

I use the following code to read the whole genome sequence. However, I just want the sequence of one chromosome (e.g. whole sequence of Chr2). Rather than reading the whole genome, then searching the pattern for Chr2, is there any other way I could do this?

Thank you

```
   with open("genome.txt") as f:
       for line in f:
           genome.append(line.rstrip())
```

Comment: You'll have to iterate over each line (that is, actually read the line), and when you encounter `Chr2`, start storing the read lines until you encounter `Chr3` and then you can stop storing the lines. If you're concerned about speed, you could store the chromosomes in a database where you could make use of an index on chromosomes to quickly find them.

Comment: Store individual chromosome sequence in a database might be a good idea, while I don't have much experience with database.  I could save each chromosome sequence in a separate file, then load the one I want might work.     Thanks for the comments.

Comment: sqlite comes bundled with Python. However, storing the chromosomes in separate files may be sufficient. You can then use `os.listdir` and `bisect` to find the chromosome file that you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the file and read line by line until you find 'Chr2'.

Consume all non-empty lines until you reach EOF or any line beginning with 'Chr'

```
def getgenomes(gfile):
    g = []
    for line in gfile:
        if line.startswith('Chr'):
            break
        if (line := line.strip()):
            g.append(line)
    return g

with open('genome.txt', encoding='utf-8') as gfile:
    genomes = None
    for line in gfile:
        if line.startswith('Chr2'):
            genomes = getgenomes(gfile)
            break
    print(genomes)
```

**output:**

```
['TGCGTGATGCTGAGCGATGCTGATGCT', 'TAGCTGACCACACACCTGTTTTGTAGG']
```

Comment: For the getgenomes helper function, do you mean                                                                                                                
 `for line in gfile:
    if line.startswith('Chr'):
        break.                                                                                                                       
    else:
        g.append(line)`.

Comment: @Liyong No. That is not what I meant. The file may contain blank/empty lines. We don't want them

Answer (score -2):

```
Is_Chr2 = False

with open("genome.txt") as f:
   for line in f:
       if Is_Chr2: genome.append(line.rstrip())
       if line.rstrip() == "Chr2": Is_Chr2 = True
       else if line.rstrip()[:2] == "Chr" and Is_Chr2: break
```

Comment: How do you get the lines of interest from this?

Comment: They are appended to the list `genome` in line 5

Comment: Oh yes. I missed that. So it appears that you will continue reading the file even when you observe the sequence that follows Chr2 (Chr3). Wouldn't it make sense to stop reading when there's obviously nothing more of any relevance?

Comment: Good point. I've changed it so that it breaks if it would be switching from true to false.